# Regex expression to filter URLs

Tags: regex

How to write regex and differentiate between a) top level URL and b) for links inside these top level URLs.

```
For e.g, if the top level url is http://www.example.com/ 

and other links inside this top folder can be,
http://www.example.com/go
http://www.example.com/contact/
http://www.example.com/links/
```

I do not know what links are inside the top folder, is there a regex that can select the main one and also all of these sub folders inside the main one.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.example.go.com/ is a different URL..

Comment: have a look at [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: do you want to validate the URL as well?

Comment: No i do not want to validate them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting with a regex that breaks an url into its components. There are many examples. This one is taken from Jan Goyvaerts, author of *The Regex Cookbook*:

```
(?i)\b(?<protocol>https?|ftp)://(?<domain>[-A-Z0-9.]+)(?<file>/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(?<parameters>\?[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?
```

The different segments of the URL are available in various capture groups (in the **[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dU5lQ3/11)**, look at the Groups in the right pane.)

Then, if you want to match fewer components, shorten the regex:

```
^(?im)\b(?<protocol>https?|ftp)://(?<domain>[-A-Z0-9.]+)/?$
```

See in **[the second demo](http://regex101.com/r/dU5lQ3/12)** how this one matches the url without the files.

Comment: FYI added a second demo for shorter urls.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't want to validate the URL hence simply get the matched groups from index 1(the top level url) and 2 (anything followed by the top level url) that is captured by enclosing it inside the parenthesis `(...)`

```
^http:\/\/([^\/]*)\/(.*)$
```

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aI4nM5/2) and click on `code generator link` to get the code as well in desired language.

Pattern explanation:

```
  ^                        the beginning of the string
  http:                    'http:'
  \/                       '/'
  \/                       '/'
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    [^\/]*                   any character except: '\/' (0 or more times (Greedy))
  )                        end of \1
  \/                       '/'
  (                        group and capture to \2:
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times (Greedy))
  )                        end of \2
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

---

If the URLs are inside the string or span in multi-line then use below regex:

```
\bhttp:\/\/([^\/]*)\/([^\s]*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aI4nM5/3)